# Adverts on Bioinfo SE

Tags: discussion

There is currently, essentially an advert on Bioinfo SE in another disguise  [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/12865/where-is-a-good-place-to-find-experienced-ongoing-bioinformatics-help). Is there any fast-track system for removing it without the standard "close vote" system?

The "close vote" system works well because there are clear grey-zones and it safe-guards equivocal judgement calls, but there has to fast-track system that circumvents this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way is to ping me or another moderator in the chat room. I should get a notification on my phone and be able to quickly close/delete such things.

Please note that I'll eventually notice flagged posts, but it might take a couple hours.

Comment: Thanks, @DevonRyan good to know and thanks for shutting the post down.